# When i try do a cast dates to char and the timestamp part is getting removed

Tags: sql, oracle

nvl(cast(effective_DAte as varchar(100)),' ')

The above is the function i try to apply

When i do this the timestamp in the date is getting removed.Please help

Comment: What type is `effective_date`? Is it a `DATE`, `TIMESTAMP`, or `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`?

Answer (score 0):

Dates do have a time component in Oracle (confusingly and unlike other databases).  By default, I guess Oracle wants people to forget that and only considers the date when converting to a string.

In general, the recommendation is to use `to_char()` so you can control the format:

```
select to_char(effective_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

If you want the default format along with the time, you can cast the date as a timestamp and then convert to a string:

```
select to_char(cast(effective_date as timestamp))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response.This really helped

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . You can remove the comment.  That should have been the OP's column.